# Use rank with get_json_object

Tags: json, hive, hiveql

I want to read JSON data using get_json_object but add a rownumber within a group by scenario.

I have tried;

This is the select before adding the rownumber/rank

```
select get_json_object(json_data.fullrow, '$.event.type\[0]') as player_event,
get_json_object(json_data.fullrow, '$.stringDate\[0]') as date,
get_json_object(json_data.fullrow, '$.sessionID\[0]') as user_session
from json_data;
```

I want to add a row number to the player_event's grouped by user_session, along these lines.

```
player_event,user_session,date,rank
START,1,010114,1
MIDDLE,1,010114,2
FINISH,1,010114,3
START,2,010114,1
FINISH,2,010114,2


SELECT 
get_json_object(json_data.fullrow, '$.event.type\[0]') as player_event, 
get_json_object(json_data.fullrow, '$.sessionID\[0]') as user_session,
get_json_object(json_data.fullrow, '$.stringDate\[0]') as date,
rank() over (PARTITION BY get_json_object(json_data.fullrow, '$.sessionID\[0]') as user_session  order by get_json_object(json_data.fullrow, '$.stringDate\[0]') as date desc) as rank
FROM json_data
```

I get the following error;

```
FAILED: ParseException line 5:80 missing ) at 'as' near 'user_session' in table name
line 5:96 missing FROM at 'order' near 'user_session' in table name
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to test your exact scenario, but I would suggest rewriting the query so that the `get_json_object` calls are in a `sub-query` and then make use of them for `ranking`.

```
select tmp.player_event, tmp.user_session, tmp.date, rank() over (partition by tmp.user_session order by tmp.date) as rnk
from
(
SELECT 
get_json_object(json_data.fullrow, '$.event.type\[0]') as player_event, 
get_json_object(json_data.fullrow, '$.sessionID\[0]') as user_session,
get_json_object(json_data.fullrow, '$.stringDate\[0]') as date
FROM json_data) tmp
;
```

Comment: visakh, superb!   many thanks for responding, it works perfectly.